# How to get input values from mgt-people-picker when a FORM is submitted

Tags: asp.net, razor, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I'm using `mgt-people-picker` from within an ASP.Net Razor application, using a `ProxyController` to get all the data from the Graph API.
Everything is working fine.

Now I want to get the infos from a Form I've created, containing a people list, from the `mgt-people-picker` element :

[image]

From my ASP.NET backend, once the form is submitted; I have all the info from my inputs, except the `mgt-people-picker` element.

[image]

Anyone knows a simple solution to get the list of people form the input text, issued during the POST action ?

Or should we use a javascript trick ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone has the same issue, here is the solution, after a LOT of investigations.

You have to use the **template** of `<mgt-people-picker>` with `data-type=selected-person`.
In this template section, you need to add

- An `<mgt-person>` with the correct properties (That I've found in the source code)
- An `<input type=hidden />` to store the values:

```
<mgt-people-picker>
    <template data-type="selected-person">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{person.userPrincipalName}}" name="people" id="people" />
        <mgt-person view="oneLine" person-details="{{person}}" fetchImage=true></mgt-person>
    </template>
</mgt-people-picker>
```

From within your backend handler, you will get all the persons selected in the `Request.Form["people"]` property

```cs
public void OnPost()
{
    foreach (var personSelected in Request.Form["people"])
        Debug.WriteLine(personSelected);

}
```

The solution is **elegant** and **easy** to use & understand.
Unfortunatelly, the documentation lacks details on the customization, especially on templates :)